# MacVIM 7.3 throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macvim

I recently installed MacVim 7.3 on my mac (MacOs 10.6.8) and now when I type Vim, I am getting this error. I also installed this git: `git://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles.git .vim`

```
E254: Cannot allocate color Red
E254: Cannot allocate color White
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color Red
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color Brown
E254: Cannot allocate color SeaGreen
E254: Cannot allocate color SeaGreen
E254: Cannot allocate color Yellow
E254: Cannot allocate color Red
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color Magenta
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkCyan
E254: Cannot allocate color LightMagenta
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color Magenta
E254: Cannot allocate color Red
E254: Cannot allocate color Yellow
E254: Cannot allocate color Black
E254: Cannot allocate color LightGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkBlue
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkBlue
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkBlue
E254: Cannot allocate color LightGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color LightBlue
E254: Cannot allocate color LightMagenta
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color LightCyan
E254: Cannot allocate color LightGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey90
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey90
E254: Cannot allocate color LightRed
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color LightGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color Cyan
Error detected while processing /Users/myusername/.vimrc:
line  216:
E484: Can't open file /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOs/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
line  266:
E185: Cannot find color scheme default
line  314:
E484: Can't open file /Users/myusername/vimfiles/snippets/support_functions.vim
```

Anyone experienced the same issue and has a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it could be a permissions issue and you might not have a 256 color supported $TERM. Make sure you have permissions on the `/Applications/MacVim.app/**` files and that you're using a 256 color terminal. For example, `echo $TERM`, `==> xterm`, `export TERM=xterm-256color`.

Comment: I checked the permissions and I do have access. Changed the TERM to be xterm-256color but I am still getting the error.

Comment: where did you install the github repository? Is it in /Users/myusername/.vim? Does /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOs/vim/runtime exist with the usual runtime files?